# How to calculate the correct change by item group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of products with the daily price that changes every day.  I would like to calculate the price change by product by resampling on a different time basis (monthly, yearly, ...) but I get a calculation error on the first time series.

Here is an example of my dataframe with 2 products:

```
df_change = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05'], 
                          'price' : [20, 30, 40, 10, 15, 200, 220, 230, 200, 190],
                          'symbol': ['AI', 'AI', 'AI', 'AI', 'AI', 'PR', 'PR', 'PR', 'PR', 'PR']
                         })
datetime_series = pd.to_datetime(df_change['date'])
```

Here is the mean price on a 2-day resampling basis per product:

```
df_change.groupby('symbol').resample('2D').mean():
AI  2020-04-01  25
    2020-04-03  25
    2020-04-05  15
PR  2020-04-01  210
    2020-04-03  215
    2020-04-05  190
```

And to calculate the change of these prices:

```
df_change.groupby('symbol').resample('2D').mean().pct_change()
AI  2020-04-01  NaN
    2020-04-03  0.000000
    2020-04-05  -0.400000
PR  2020-04-01  13.000000 <=== not correct
    2020-04-03  0.023810
    2020-04-05  -0.116279
```

But the change of the product "PR" of the first time series "13.000" is not correct.
The change should be NaN like the first product AI.

The variation "13" of PR has been calculated with the last time series of the previous product AI.
13 = (210 - 15) / 15

How can I get the correct calculation of the change for each first time series per product? (that's to say Nan)

Answer (score 0):

Perform additional `groupby` operation after calculating the rolling `mean` to calculate the percent change

```
avg = df_change.groupby('symbol').resample('2D').mean()
avg_change = avg.groupby('symbol').pct_change()
```

Alternatively you can `resample` , `mean` and calculate `pct_change` inside the `apply` method of `groupby` object

```
avg_change = df_change.groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: x.resample('2D').mean().pct_change())
```

---

```
>>> avg_change

                      price
symbol date                
AI     2020-04-01       NaN
       2020-04-03  0.000000
       2020-04-05 -0.400000
PR     2020-04-01       NaN
       2020-04-03  0.023810
       2020-04-05 -0.116279
```